# mod_rewrite multiple fake subdirectories

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, path, subdirectory

Sorry if this is a really dumb question - I can't find the answer anywhere...

I'm storing my test files in a subdirectory called 'dev', and using the following rewrite rule so that requests to `/dev/VAR1/VAR2` will take me to `/index.php?page=VAR1/VAR2`, and requests to `/dev/VAR1/` will take me to `/index.php?page=VAR1`
(VAR1 and VAR2 are variables, and the folders/subdirectories won't really exist)

```
RewriteBase /dev
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z/\-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

This is doing it fine - my index.php is getting the right variables. The problem is that the server or page (or I don't understand what...) thinks I'm *actually* in the non-existent folder (or subdirectory) which is VAR1, so all my relative (if that's the right word) addresses for images and links and css and scripts etc

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./sitefiles/mystyles.css" />
```

all work as if they were `/dev/VAR1/sitefiles/mystyles.css` - basically, the server thinks it's actually in the 'fake' folder.

Is there a way I can continue to use these relative addresses with my mod_rewrite, or do I have to use 'absolute' addresses with the complete path?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1426302/53114

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're using the same stuff with our configuration and rewriting fake aliases to index.php?something=$1 we have to put our CSS files into the /styles/ of the DocumentRoot and don't use relative ./ path use the absolute path like  href="/sitefiles/mystyles.css" it should work fine.